# SSD for Samsung NP RC-530 S05IT

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd

I have a Samsung np rc530 s05 - I7 - 6gb RAM ddr3 notebook, with a little, slow hard disk.

I wish to swap it with an SSD, more specifically with a Samsung 850 evo.

I've read in some discussions in different forums something about SATA II/SATA III (I don't really understand this topic).

I made some tests on my PC, and I think that my notebook is not SATA III (even if I think that I'm in wrong because my PC is pretty modern).

My question is:

If I'm going to buy the SSD Samsung 850 evo, i can have some trouble with the SSD socket and its functionality?

Or am I wrong to focus on the SSD socket and they are universal and at worst I won't have the max performance from SSD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is true that you can plug a SATA III Drive into a SATA II port, you will only receive SATA II speeds.

- SATA III has a "max" transfer rate of 6Gbps (In real terms, this is about 600MBps)
- SATA II has a "max" transfer rate of 3Gbps (Half of SATA III)
- The Samsung 850 EVO drive has a "max" transfer rate of over 500MBps for both reads and writes

By using that specific SSD in a SATA II port, you will only ever see at most 300MBps, or only about 60% of the speeds it could reach on a SATA III interface.

Comment: thanks very much for your help. Your explanation is very useful for me. Have a nice day